# Assistance with @DbLookup code

Tags: lotus-notes, formula, lotus-formula

In my current database, I am trying to open a view from another database using

Here is my database formula

```
CurrServer := @ServerName;
HistPath := @DbLookup("":"NoCache"; "":""; "AdminKeys"; "DatabaseReferencePMWOHist"; 2);
CurrServer + "!!" + HistPath
```

When I click on the link in the application, it throws this error: File 'DomTest01/HCHtest  Engineering\PMWorkOrderMgmtHist.nsf' does not exist.

I am on DomTest01 server, but it needs to be looking for aApplications\PMWorkOrderMgmt.nsf instead of Engineering\PMWorkOrderMgmtHist.nsf

Where do I need to make my change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `@DbLookup` gets the database's path from second column under key "DatabaseReferencePMWOHist" in view "AdminKeys" in your current database.

So, the only thing you have to do, is to go into view "AdminKeys", search for key "DatabaseReferencePMWOHist", open the document and change value from "Engineering\PMWorkOrderMgmtHist.nsf" to "aApplications\PMWorkOrderMgmt.nsf".

Your code should work without any changes - only a setting in a document is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of the [@DbLookup](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_DBLOOKUP_NOTES_DATABASES.html?resultof=%22@DbLookup%22%20%22dblookup%22%20) formula tells what server and database to use.  If you want to search another database on the current server you are on, use this command:

```
CurrServer := @ServerName;
HistPath := @DbLookup("":"NoCache"; "":"aApplications\\PMWorkOrderMgmt.nsf"; "AdminKeys"; "DatabaseReferencePMWOHist"; 2);
CurrServer + "!!" + HistPath
```

Comment: When I put that in, I get this error message: Adding entry will cause text list to exceed 64k. Entry not added.